# How do you change mapping between textures?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have a diffuse texture mapped onto an object in the node editor. What I want is to map another texture on only part of the mesh over the original diffuse texture. But, when I go to the UV editor and switch from the original texture to the new texture and move the mapping of the mesh on the new texture, it changes the mapping for the original texture too! Is there a way to unlink these mapping modifications?

Comment: What render engine do you use? Which Blender version? In Cycles mapping can be set up in the nodes separately for each texture via adding Texture Coordinates node and Mapping node one after another plugged into coordinates of the texture.

Comment: You can also create a new UV map and use that to control the second texture. The first UV map (and materials that use it) should be unaffected by changes.